# django view 'GET' does not work, 'POST' does work

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I have no Idea why, but if I try to 'GET' this view I get this error:

`django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'profile-update-name' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['ce_profiles/profile\\-update\\-name/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']`

But if submit a 'POST' request, everything is fine. ???

Here is the work flow:

First I access this view and template:

```
def customer_profile(request, pk):
    name = get_object_or_404(CEName, id=pk)
    return render(
        request,
        'customer/customer_profile.html',
        {'profile_name': name}
    )

{% block content %}
  {% include 'ce_profiles/name_header.html' %}
  <div id="name" class="container d-flex justify-content-between pt-1">
    {% include 'ce_profiles/profile_name.html' %} <!-- displays the profile_name -->
    <button id="update_button" action="{% url 'ce_profiles:profile-update-name' profile_name.id %}" class="bold btn btn-main btn-sm button-main">UPDATE</button>
  </div>
  <div id="div_NameForm" class="container">
  </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block script %}
  <script src="{% static 'ce_profiles/ce_profiles.js' %}"></script>

{% endblock %}
```

When I click the update button it should AJAX in the form to be modified. I've tried substitution of the variable to just a '1', but it still doesn't work. I have tests to verify that the view by itself doesn't work with the 'GET', but does with the 'POST', apart from the previous view.

urls.py

```
app_name='ce_profiles'
urlpatterns = [
    path('profile-update-name/<int:pk>/', views.profile_update_name,
        name='profile-update-name'
    ),
]
```

view

```
def profile_update_name(request, pk):
    name = get_object_or_404(CEName, id=pk)
    if request.POST:
        name_form = NameForm(data=request.POST, instance=name)
        if name_form.has_changed() == False:
            name_form.add_error(None, _('No changes made.'))
        if name_form.is_valid():
            name_form.save()
            updated_name = get_object_or_404(CEName, id=name.id)
            profile_name_json = render_to_string(
                'ce_profiles/profile_name.html',
                {'profile_name': updated_name,}
            )
            return JsonResponse({'profile_name': profile_name_json})
        else:
          return JsonResponse({'error': name_form.errors})
    else:
        name_form = NameForm(instance=name)
        get_NameForm_json = render_to_string(
            'ce_profiles/update_NameForm.html',
            {'NameForm': name_form}
        )
        return JsonResponse({'NameForm': get_NameForm_json})
```

Here is the template. Is something missing?

update_NameForm.html

```
<div id="div_NameForm" class="container">
  <hr size="3px">
  <form id="NameForm" method="POST" action="{% url 'ce_profiles:profile-update-name' profile_name.id %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ NameForm.as_p }}
    <div id="NameForm_errors"></div>
    <br>
    <button id="save_changes" type="submit" class="btn btn-main button-main btn-block">Save Changes</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: probably a link in yout update_NameForm.html template that refers to a name not defined in your urls.py files

Comment: @vctrd I added the template

Comment: can you show the template that the views renders?

Comment: you  don't send this variable to the template : `profile_name`, so `profile_name.id` will be None

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `render_to_string`, you may use `render()`, and you forgot to send the variable `profile_name`: to the templates.

```
def profile_update_name(request, pk):
    name = get_object_or_404(CEName, id=pk)
    if request.POST:
       ''' code '''

    # no need to use else statement
    # since 'return' breaks the 'if request.POST' statement
    name_form = NameForm(instance=name)
    context = {
        profile_name:name,
        'NameForm': name_form,
    }
    return render(request,'ce_profiles/update_NameForm.html',context)
```

Note that you can you leave `action=''` empty in the form which will mean the same view

```
 <form id="NameForm" method="POST" action="">
```

Comment: I need to `render_to_string` to AJAX my form to another view, but the `'profile_name': name` totally fixed it.

Comment: You're going to have to show me that one. I had a hard time figuring out how to AJAX a multiple-field form to a view and get a response back. Somebody should make a decent tutorial for that. I couldn't get `render()` to work.

Comment: it depends on how you handle the response in `js`, the response will be different

Comment: `[render_to_string()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.render_to_string)`  loads a template like get_template(), so you may use in js `element.html(response)` since response is just a string...  render() shortcut calls render_to_string() and feeds the result into an HttpResponse suitable for returning from a view, in js you may manipulate the response as a js object.. like you can query selector inside the response.. `$(response).find('#tag')` I don't have any links sorry

Comment: I'm just not connecting the dots right now. I think I need to see the completed code for it sink in. Thanks for the help.